# Article Detail page is not displaying in Napili Community template

Tags: community, articles, napili

In Napili Template, article detail page is not opening and instead displays this error message:

> The Article Detail page relies on your Salesforce data and because you don't yet have any relevant content, the page can't be displayed. Add some appropriate content and try again.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the message make sure you have at least one article and you are able to view that  article .

Once you are viewing the article then switch back to the builder lightning page editor .

Follow the below steps

1.Make sure your profile has access to the article type

2.Make sure the Topic is enabled for article type

[image]

3.Publish an article by allowing necessary channels and data category

4.Assign Topic to Knowledge article via Article management Tab

[image]

5.View the article using branding editor menu

[image]

6.Switch back to the editor

[image]